# How can I read variables from a JMeter test plan in my code?

Tags: java, jmeter

Within my java code, how can I access a value stored in the JMeter test plan (jmx file)? Specifically trying to get ThreadGroup.num_threads so my test code can know how many threads are being used in the test.

Thanks for the replies. Here's the code I ended up using:

```
    int testThreadCount = 0;
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document testPlanFile = builder.parse(new File("path/to/testplan.jmx"));
    NodeList nodes = testPlanFile.getElementsByTagName("stringProp");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i)
    {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        Element element = (Element)node;
        String propName = element.getAttribute("name");
        if (propName.equals("ThreadGroup.num_threads"))
        {
            testThreadCount = Integer.parseInt(element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you mean in a custom java sampler?

Answer (score 4):

1. Java way (if you're about to get values from .jmx file using [Java API and XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html))

   ```
   DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

   DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

   Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new File("/path/to/test.jmx"));

   XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
   String expression = "//hashTree/ThreadGroup/stringProp[@name='ThreadGroup.num_threads']/text()";
   NodeList matches = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

   for (int i = 0; i < matches.getLength(); ) {
       System.out.println("Thread Group " + (i + 1) + " users = " + matches.item(i).getTextContent());
       i++;
   }
   ```
2. JMeter way (if you're using [JMeter API to read .jmx file](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui))

   ```
   JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/jmeter.properties");
   JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/path/to/jmeter");
   JMeterUtils.initLogging();
   JMeterUtils.initLocale();


   SaveService.loadProperties();


   StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

   HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/to/test.jmx"));

   JMeterTreeModel treeModel = new JMeterTreeModel(new Object());
   JMeterTreeNode root = (JMeterTreeNode) treeModel.getRoot();
   treeModel.addSubTree(testPlanTree, root);

   SearchByClass<ThreadGroup> threadGroups = new SearchByClass<>(ThreadGroup.class);
   testPlanTree.traverse(threadGroups);
   Collection<ThreadGroup> threadGroupsRes = threadGroups.getSearchResults();
   for (ThreadGroup threadGroup : threadGroupsRes) {
       System.out.println(threadGroup.getProperty("ThreadGroup.num_threads"));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In a custom java sampler that extends `AbstractJavaSamplerClient`, you have access to the `JavaSamplerContext` object, which exposes a bunch of run time properties

```
@Override
public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
    ...
    // get parameters:
    String urlString = context.getParameter( "paramName" );
    ...
}
```

You can get thread information at runtime from [`JMeterContextService`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html). Current number of active threads is

```
JMeterContextService.getNumberOfThreads()
```

Comment: When I tried both `JMeterContextService.getNumberOfThreads()` and `JMeterContextService.getTotalThreads()` I only ever saw 0 for the first and either 1 or 0 for the second, even when I'd configured the jmeter thread group to 7 threads.